# Make Android project Gradle compatible in Android 1.0 or above

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

All I'm creating android library, I want make that library for every Android version, I have set minimum `SDK 1.0` but there is problem when import any library in gradle like I set the Volley library, but there is issue of `minSdkVersion`.

Here is my Gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 1
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

//androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
//androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'}
```

Comment: The libraries that you depend on should have the older support as well. Otherwise, you cannot use them.

Comment: Android 1? Why? https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Interesting I just tried to set the minSdkVersion to 1 in Android Studio and it actually gave me this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] C:\Users\apoll.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\59796637ea8f62835a30730f9cea1b8a\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 1
>       Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1,
>           or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 14,
>           or use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Ideally you can target everything >= 16 as it covers almost all devices no a days.

I'd recommend only covering 21 and above though as a lot of UI bugs exist when developing an app with the support library and it would significantly reduce your QA and dev time.